# IOS App Support Page URL

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a simple question. while we submit our app to IOS App store, iTunesConnect has a section for **Application Support URL**. Is it must to create a URL page ( page must exist?) as now I just pointed the url to a directory under my website such as http://example.com/directory (this is just an example of url)

What if there is no content in that page? Will Apple reject my app? Should I create an html page about my application?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you have to provide a URL as it complains that the field is required if you leave it empty.

I do not think they will reject it but for the users' sake I would create a simple website maybe containing your email address so they can actually use the *Application Support* feature.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will Try to create something simple